# Get last clicked element in multiple select Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to get the last clicked option in a multiple select, no matters if the option is selected or unselected.
The problem is that the select is not via template, is mounted dinamically via TS.

I've tried adding vanilla JS event listeners at the creation of the options but doesn't works. Actually i can get all the selected elements, but i lost the unselected option and i can't get exactly the new selected one.

My HTML

```html
<tr *ngFor="let communityLine of communityLines">
      <td>{{communityLine.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.instrument.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.param.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.contextSource.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.sampleType.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.value}}</td>
      <td>

        <select multiple [id] ="communityLine.apiKey" (change)="eventGetChange(communityLine, $event)" [(ngModel)]="nodeKey">
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

My TS function

```js
private eventGetChange(commLineKey, event) {
    console.log(this.nodeKey);
    console.log(commLineKey);
    console.log(event.target.value)
```

My TS method to mount the select, is a bit complicated because i need to show all nodes (stored in this.allNodes var) but select the nodes that are in other array (nodesInRelation var).

```js
private mountSelect(nodesInRelation: Node[], lineApiKey: String): void {
    let select = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById(lineApiKey);
    let copy = this.allNodes;
    for (let node of nodesInRelation) {
      copy.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item.name === node.name) copy.splice(index, 1);
      });
    }
    for (let node of nodesInRelation) {
      let newoption = new Option(node.name, node.apiKey, null, true);
      select.add(newoption);
    }

    for (let node of copy) {
      let newoption = new Option(node.name, node.apiKey, null, false);
      select.add(newoption);
    }
    M.updateTextFields();
    M.AutoInit();
  }
```

In eventGetChange function first console.log i get all the current selected values, in the second i get the key and is okey and in the third i get only  the first selected element in the box.

I just want the last clicked, selected or unselected.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be ditching Angular and opting for direct DOM manipulation for no apparent reason. Angular is perfectly capable of populating options list programmatically. It could look something like

```
      <td>
        <select multiple [id] ="communityLine.apiKey" [(ngModel)]="nodeKey">
            <option *ngFor="let option of optionList; let i = index"
               [value]="option" (click)="eventGetChange(option)">{{ option }}
            </option>
        </select>
      </td>
```

```
optionList: any[];

private mountSelect(nodesInRelation: Node[], lineApiKey: String): void {
// populate optionList here
}

private eventGetChange(commLineKey) {
// the clicked option is available here
}
```

Comment: But in my Node object I don't have the selected attribute... Maybe I need to make some deep changes. Thanks you

Comment: And the optionList will be different in each communityLine loop

Answer (score 0):

If this.nodeKey as you say stores an array with all the current selected values you can simply do this:

```
this.nodeKey[this.nodeKey.length - 1]
```

It will give you the las value in the nodeKey array

Comment: This doesn't works because i don't get the last unselected element and if the user selects an element that is before the next selected i get the next seleted.

Comment: I mean, if you have a select with all options unselected and you click the third one and then the second you will get the third one

Comment: If the nodeKey contains all the values selected, and you evaluate it on the change event it should get the current select values, if not, then you defined the job of that variable incorrectly

Comment: Anyway @mbojko approach its better for this

Comment: Yes, the node key has all the selected values, but I lost the last unselected value.